# One-hot vs Grouping for Feature Engineering

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding, feature-engineering

**note I don't have 10 rep yet so I can't post images

Working with the [Adult Census](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/adult-census-income/code?datasetId=225&sortBy=voteCount) (goal is to predict which observed people will have an annual income greater than $50k/year) dataset for some ML practice and had a question for feature engineering...

The dataset has columns, of which 8 are categorical (workclass, education (dropped because integer education.num exists), marital.status, occupation, relationship, race, sex, native.country, and income)

[these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2t7f.png)

In doing analysis, I first changed income to 1 for >$50K/year and 0 for <$50K/year.

```
data['income'] = data['income'].replace({'<=50K':0, '>50K' :1})
```

However, when looking at the other variables, I needed some guidance/advice on how to approach them. For example, the 'workclass' column

```
plt.figure(figsize = (15,5))
sns.barplot(x = data['workclass'], y = data['income'])
plt.xlabel('Working Class')
plt.ylabel('Likelihood of income >= 50K')
plt.show()
```

[workclass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt63v.png)

My first idea was to use one-hot encoding, however, like `workclass`, `native.country`, `race`,`marital.status`, and `occupation` are all **unordered**. This would create nearly 100 columns.

My next idea was to manually group them based on the probability of a certain column value having an income >$50K, picked based on plots like the one below

[Martital.Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb8al.png)

Going by this, my inclination for each column would be

| Column | Feature Engineering Decision |
| --- | --- |
| workclass | drop |
| marital.status | Group (married+present = 1, not married/estranged = 0 |
| occupation | Group (white collar jobs (exec,prof,tech,sales) = 1, blue collar (all else) = 0 |
| race | Unsure, only 5 variables so could one-hot or group by white vs non-white? |
| relationship | Group (Husband or Wife = 1, No marital relationship = 0 |
| sex | One-hot, or Male = 1, Female = 0, Unsure need input |
| native.country | Tons of variables, I think Group by US vs non-US makes most sense |

[Here](https://github.com/ConorPAnderson/adult_census_income/blob/main/Income_Analysis.ipynb) is a link to the full jupyter notebook with graphs for all categorical variables. So, can you help me decide if this is the right way to feature engineer the columns in my dataset?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Adult Census is a classic toy dataset, I can't recall all the details so my answer may not be as informative as you expect. Still, I love everything about your decisions except maybe this idea:

> My next idea was to manually group them based on the probability of a certain column value having an income >$50K, picked based on plots like the one below

Since your goal is to build a model that predicts income status for unobserved individuals, associating your categories directly with target will likely lead to overfitting; in test data, the distributions of categories can differ from those in training data. However, it does not mean that you shouldn't consider target classes at all. Indeed, try calculating probabilities on *subsamples* of your category columns or adding noise to the obtained probabilities. See [`category_encoders`](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/) package for inspiration. Good luck!

P.S. Are `workclass` and `education.num` really identical?